# Is it possible to connect to the camera remote app without running a discovery request before?

Tags: camera, sony

I'm trying to access to the list of photos on my A7 & A6000 from my linux computer. I thought about using the camera remote API to do so, but I can't get any answer from the camera. I connect to the wireless network of the app, I know the IP address of the camera, and I'm trying to send a JSON query to the 8080 port, but no answer.

Is it necessary to run a discovery request before ? Maybe the IP & port that I'm using are wrong. I used examples from some code I found online, thinking it would be faster to query the camera directly since its IP seemed to be always the same. What am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading the SDK and looking at the sample code if you haven't already done so:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/get-started/

Even though the sample code is based on Android/iOS, you should be able to see how the connection is setup and replicate it in your own code.